# Creating menus at runtime depending on user role

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, menu

I am trying to create a menu that sorts differently depending on what the user role is.

For example, if the user is an Admin role, the menu shown will be:

> - AdminPane
> - RegisterUser
> - UserRoles

and if the user is Basic role:

> - ViewProducts
> - makeOrder

This is a layout example.

I would appreciate some help as I've been searching the net for 2 hours with no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: is this a ASP.NET web application..? if so use master pages and set the visibility of the tabs or menus from there I've used this approach many times when authenticating user groups roles ontop of ActiveDirectory

Comment: There's very little information here.  What exactly is a "menu" in this case?  How are your existing "menus" created?  Are you just building them in a master page?  Maybe have both menus on the master page and just show/hide them with a conditional which checks the role of the logged-in user?

Comment: Im sorry but i did not understand what you just said... and yes it is an asp.net web application, i was going to do it as a user control and drag it in the masterpage..

Comment: you don't need a user control this could all be controlled via code behind..

Comment: Well im creating the menu at runtime, menu items at runtime depending on the user role, what you just said aint a bad idea at all but first I want to try it my way then if unsuccessful I will go to your idea :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is in your web.config have a section in your `system.web` section, like so:

```
    <siteMap>
        <providers>
            <add name="anonymous" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/YourAnonymouse.sitemap"/>
            <add name="user" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/YourNormalUser.sitemap"/>
            <add name="admin" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/YourAdmin.sitemap"/>
        </providers>
    </siteMap>
```

Then with this, you'll have three site map providers defined, each pointing to their respective `sitemap` files for the necessary menu you are looking for for each user type.

Then you'll have a `SiteMapDataSource` that your menu server control will use.  This will most likely exist on your master page.  On your `Page_Load()` of your master page you'll have logic to dynamically and programmatically set the sitemap data source of your `SiteMapDataSource` control:

```
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            SiteMapDataSource1.Provider = SiteMap.Providers("admin");
        else
            SiteMapDataSource1.Provider = SiteMap.Providers("user");
    }
    else
        SiteMapDataSource1.Provider = SiteMap.Providers("anonymous");
```

Answer (score 0):

All of this can be accomplished by using MasterPages and on Postback or Initial Page load you can create a Session Variable that stores the values or write something against ActiveDirectory fairly simple..